# Powershell script to copy and rename to file path found

Tags: powershell, file-rename, copy-item

Looking for a PS script to copy file from network path *with wildcards* to local HDD and rename file from where file had been obtained from:

```
copy-item -path \\SC****SVR0001\E$\Users\SC****POS00**\TEST.INI -destination 'C:\TEST\
```

Resulting in rename to be something like "SC****POS00**_TEST.INI" where I obtained the file.

The SC****SVR0001 file path I will get approx. 200 results, and the SC****POS00** I would get potentially 13+ results.

Hope I explained that well enough!

Getting close with this...

```
$Source1 = "\\SCXXXXSVR0001\E$\Users\*\TEST.INI"
$destination1 = "E:\Test\Results\"
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path $destination1

Write-Verbose "Number of items: $($items.Count)" -Verbose

foreach ($item in $items)
{
Write-Verbose "Item: $item" -Verbose
# use -Force here? Does $_ have a DirectoryName property?
#
#Copy-Item -Path $Source1 -Destination $_.DirectoryName

Copy-Item -Path $Source1 -Destination $item -Force -WhatIf
}
```

HOWEVER, does not copy ANY files.

Comment: What is the purpose of `$_.npath`? See the [MSDN page on `Copy-Item`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/4.0/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item) for a full explanation of the syntax.

Comment: Please describe in more detail what you expect the result to be. Do you want the destination file (in C:\TEST, in your example) to be renamed, or are you trying to rename the original file (on the network share)?

Comment: If you're copying from a known path, as your example shows, then you can just explicitly use that as the destination name - did you check the MSDN page I linked to before? If, on the other hand, you are doing a wildcard search for items to copy, you'll need to do a little manipulation of the path, which gets a little more complicated. Which more accurately describes your situation? Your question should be edited to reflect that.

Comment: Revamped to accurately describe what I am looking for, I trust this will be complex, but tried to break it down 1 by 1.  Alas, there is what I am officially looking for.

Comment: For getting the folder name to combine with the destination file name, you might find the [Split-Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path) cmdlet useful. The [`-split` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/4.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split) might be useful as well.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, any guidance with the -split command would be greatly appreciated.  Not sure how I would implement with the above code.

Comment: Did you check the link to the `-split` operator I provided? As an example of how to use it, if I had the string `"C:\ONE\TWO\THREE"`, I could say `$PathArray = "C:\ONE\TWO\THREE" -split "\"` and end up with `$PathArray` being an array containing the strings `C:`, `ONE`, `TWO`, and `THREE`. `Split-Path` is customised for manipulating paths; the `-split` operator can be used with any delimited strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

`Copy-Item -Path \\NETWORKPATH\E$\Users\GOODTIMES\TEST.INI -Destination C:\Test\`

`gci C:\Test\Test.INI | ren -NewName GOODTIMES_TEST.INI`

Comment: How would I get newname.ini to rename WHERE I obtained the file - GOODTIMES\*.INI --> GOODTIMES.INI

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect what I think you are looking for?

Comment: If you want to clear the attributes of the file, try something like: `$a = get-item c:\Test\Test.INI` and then `$a.attributes = 'Normal'`

Comment: I understand the renaming structure, however, this script is going to be going much deeper than what is on the surface.  Eventually I want to obtain files across the network as a whole and need an understanding on where I obtained the file, thus a rename of the directory followed by file name is important.